# How can I replace Hibernate Validator with something else?

Tags: validation, hibernate-validator, dropwizard

I'm not the fan of Hibernate Validator. I would like to use something else (like [oval](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)) or implement my custom validation logic. What's the best way to replace Hibernate Validator with my custom validation logic?

Answer (score 0):

As Hibernate Validator (>= 4.x) is one implementation of the Bean Validation specification (`javax.validation.*` API) you can use other compliant implementations easily (of course depending on to which degree you're using HV specific APIs and functionality such as the provided custom constraints).

Bean Validation provides the concept of [custom constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) to implement custom validation logic.

That said (I'm one of the HV committers), what is it that makes you wish to use another implementation? If you found any bugs or have feature requests, you can open a ticket in our [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV). If you have an idea for improvement you'd like to discuss, you can either post to [our forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=9) or the [mailing list](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/). Any feedback matters, so be sure to speak up.